# Kali mitmAP не появляется точка доступа

Tags: kali-linux

Создаётся, но не появляется точка доступа , для создания точки пробовал стандартный адаптер и tp-link wn722n, в качестве источника использовал проводной интерфейс eth0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня был поврежден файл с репозиториями /etc/apt/sources.list

Его правильное содержание(без кавычек): 'deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib'

Также выполнил(без кавычек)(от superuser):
'wget https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2018.1_all.deb'

'apt install ./kali-archive-keyring_2018.1_all.deb'